# Not able to sent one view controller to another view controller using UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uitabbarcontroller

I am using `UITabBarController`, It has three `TabBarItem`. All are drag and drop from `XIB`. Each tab has one view. Now how to sent `NSString` value from first `TabBarItem` View to second `TabBarItem` View. I am not able to send the value. Here is my code:

```
tableViewIns = [[TableViewController alloc]init];

    tableViewIns.yearInputValue  = yearTextField.text; 

    tableViewIns.principalInputValue = principalTextField.text;

    tableViewIns.interestInputValue = interestTextField.text;
```

First tab is `HomeViewController`, the second tab is `TableViewController`. How to send value from one tab to another tab.

Comment: Check have you properly synthesized all variables of TableViewController...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have properly synthesized all variables and still not getting result then try another way....
That is, define variables(in your case,there are 3)in AppDelegate....`property`and `synthesize` them...

`NSString *year,*principal,*interest;`

Now, in Firstview, declare and initialize AppDelegate variable....like

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

then, `app.year = yearTextField.text;` and define the rest like-wise.....

Now in TableViewController, same, define AppDelegate and using object...get those values ....

```
yearInputValue = [app.year intValue]; //If it is int value, otherwise remove 'intValue'.
```

and it is same for rest interest and principal.....

This is the best way to get values from one view to another....:)

Comment: My pleasure that I could help you...:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to this stuff, but I have passed values to different classes using a property.  The destination class should have it in its .h file then you can assign its value in the first .m file. I believe you also need to import the destination header file in the first one too. Apologies if this doesn't make much sense, but it's definitely worked for me, albeit not in a tabview :)